# How can I get which selector is changed from a bunch of selectors?

Tags: jquery

How can I get which is selector change from a bunch of selectors?

I have this:

```
<select id="1" multiple=true>
<option value="-1">All</option>
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
</select>

<select id="2" multiple=true>
<option value="-1">All</option>
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
</select>

<select id="3" multiple=true>
<option value="-1">All</option>
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
```

How can I know which selector is changed? Think it as a lot of selects, so I couldn't check each one separately.

I did something like:

```
var name = [];

name[0]="1";
name[1]="1";
name[2]="2";
name[3]="3";

for (var i=0; i<name.length; i++){

$("#"+ name[i]).change(function() {

    checkSelectAll(name[i], optionValues);
    optionValues = $('option:selected', this).map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

}).trigger('change');

}
```

But it doesn't work. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find which select has been changed by getting its unique ID.See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2qdrua4/)

```
$('select').change(function(evt) {
console.log(evt.target.id);
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: what is $(select)? which id?

Comment: You bind same change event using for loop.With 'select' jQuery selector I bind same change event to all selector. See this jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Comment: See console to find ID of  changed event or use alert()

Answer (score 0):

try this without the loop:

```
$('select').change(function(){
var _currentSelect = $(this);
var _currentSelection = _currentSelct.val();
});
```

this will add a change function to all selects on the page. With the $(this) selector you can access the current selected one

Comment: what could be select? which id?

Comment: so, $('select') is not the id of a specific select? I have to write just $('select')?

Comment: yes if you add a form element type to the jQuery selector it will select all elemets of this type on the page an other way is to add the same css to all elements which should be handled equally and use the $('.className') selector. to get the id of the current select you can use $(this).attr('id)